# JSF passing parameter to session bean in url

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm a JSF beginner and I have an easy JSF question but I couldn't solve the logic here. 
I open new `mv.xhtml` page via commandbutton like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{grBean.protocolName(item)}"
onclick="window.open('/SearchMap/faces/mv.xhtml?url=#{item}')">
</p:commandButton>
```

And I have `mvBean` which is a session scope. I get the url parameter with a function which is called in postconstructed init method. The method is like:

```
Map <String, String>tempMap= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();       
        if(tempMap.get("url") !=null)    
            url=tempMap.get("url");
```

The problem is here, as `mvBean` is session scoped, the init method is called only once so I can't get a new url parameter naturally.

I want to use `mvBean` as a sessionScoped coz I want to keep all the passing urls in an ArrayList.

So, how can I get the url parameter when I use session bean? Or do you have any suggestion or solution?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it in `init()`, here is a quick solution. Put this on your `mv.xtml` page, somewhere inside `<h:form>`

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onload" action="#{mvBean.checkUrl()}" autoRun="true" />
```

and move your logic from `init()` to `public void checkUrl()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good answer. I'm looking for different solutions. If no reply then I'll accept your answer. Thanks again Predrag.